# Change image dimensions to 4:3 in imagemagick without cropping the image

Tags: php, imagemagick

I have this image which I get from an API call:

[image]

On the client's website, everything is set to use 4:3 format images.

Now I tried many aproaches to change the dimensions of the image to 4:3 but it always crops the image which is not de desired result.

This code:

```
"convert /original-file.jpg -background white -gravity center -extent 4:3 jpg:new-file.jpg";
```

generates this image:

[image]

But I want this result:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you know the pixel size you want then, then a -rezise, -extent` chain should work:

```
$ convert input.png -fuzz 3% -trim -resize 400x300 -gravity center -extent 400x300 output.jpg
#                   ^         ^    ^               ^               ^
#                   |         |    |               |               Extent canvas to actually be the wanted size
#                   |         |    |               How the image should be placed when the canvas is extended
#                   |         |    Resize image to preferred size
#                   |         Remove black border
#                   Fuzz for which colors to remove, can be omitted if the image's border is the exact same color all over
```

Comment: it works but it works also without -fuzz 3% -trim. I don't know what these two commands do exactly but other then that, your answer is correct. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using ImageMagick v6, this command line will take any input image and extend its canvas to a 4:3 aspect with the input image centered. Any added background areas will be white.

```
convert image.png -background white ^
   -set page "%[fx:(w/h)<(4/3)?w*(4/3)/(w/h):w]x%[fx:(4/3)<(w/h)?h*(w/h)/(4/3):h]" ^
   -set page "+%[fx:(page.width-w)/2]+%[fx:(page.height-h)/2]" -flatten out.png
```

The command is in Windows syntax. To run it on a *nix system you'll have to change the continued-line carets "^" to backslashes "\".

There are probably simpler ways to do it with IMv7.